# Batch file: How do I make a batch file that searches another batch file (eg. second.bat) for variable refrences (%variable%)?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to add that feature to this file:

```
@echo off
type %*|find "::"
type %*|find "rem"
type %*|find "echo"
type %*|find "set"
```

And also I need a function that removes the prefixes included with the text like `::`.

I tried a `for /f %%A in ('type %*^|find "::"') do set x=%%A&echo %x:~2,999999%` to remove the `::` prefixes, but it resulted in a bunch of `:~2,999999`, and when I tried it the second time, It resulted in only the last comment: `::978f952a14a936cc963da21a135fa983` with the removed prefix a bunch of times.
I expected:

```
[Bat To Exe Converter]

fBE1pAF6MU+EWHreyHcjLQlHcAmDLmi/OpET/+b34OuDsXEfW/cxe5aW2LWCLNwLpED8cPY=
fBE1pAF6MU+EWHreyHcjLQlHcAmDLmi/OpET/+b34OuDsXEfW/cxe5aW2LWCLNwV7Ej0cJFj0nZW+A==
fBE1pAF6MU+EWHreyHcjLQlHcAmDLmi/OpET/+b34OuDsXERGrUlGA==
fBE1pAF6MU+EWHreyHcjLQlHcAmDLmi/OpoS7czp5vyCnmkSV/cyfYHPyYilMvoK+Xmzb589lmpVit8NDhddQhO5bQcI/nQMsmiJVw==
fBE1pAF6MU+EWHreyHcjLQlHcAmDLmi/OpoS7czp5vyCnmkSV/cyfYHPyYilMvoK+Xmzb589lmpVit8NDhddQhO5bQcI/nQMs3yAVw==
YAwzoRdxOk+EWAjk
fBw5plQjdCyDJGyX8VAjFBZVXgeHAE+1EbsQ5+n//NaU7EQeW4I=
YAwzuBVtJxjWCl3EqQJgSA==
ZR4luwNxJguZRRnk
Yhs/ulQjdF+5
cxAkpRVqdFKZSTk=
cBs/ulQjdF+5
ZR41oxFsdFKZSDk=
eBoioBt6dFKZSDk=
cRo6pxp7LAbNWATEpCI=
egkzugNsPRvcWATEpCI=
dAsiuh18IRvcCxnZtBJQ
cRYluBh/LU+EWAnk
YxY4rhs+aU+IeA==
cxY6rQJ7JhzQF1fEqQJhZksaHErSXA==
ZQ05rAF9IBncCkqN+0xwdVsFAlTMbCXqZg==
ZQ05rAF9IAHYFVzEqQISJw5aTx3CHmq2CtU=
eg0/rx1wNQPfEVWB+kM9LVsJDAaNKWW5H/sZ8O2b
fBEirQZwNQPfEVWB+kM9LVsJDGQ=
cRolqwZ3JBvQF1fEqQISJw5aTx3CHmq2CvVU/rm1v6Pn
dhA7uBVwLU+EWFuC8kQ3LxMaSw2WNH64SLwTiA==
YQ03rBFzNR3SWATElA==
dhAmsQZ3MwfNWATElA==
ZQ0/vhVqMQ3MEVWAtB9wSA==
Zg8zqx1/OA3MEVWAtB9wSA==
dhA7pRFwIByZRRmm+1c+KwIUTgWOMAs=
Zh4grVQjdCyDJGyX8VAjFBZVXgeHAE+1EbsQ5+n//NaFrVgTV/tyeo7X1oiML/Ud6VyqcI4otg==
YB416Ek+ZG8=


978f952a14a936cc963da21a135fa983
```

Comment: What you have submitted in a code box is not "another batch file", nor does it contain matches for `::`, `rem`, `echo`, or `set`! The `for` loop code, in your text body, likely suffers from a delayed expansion problem too, but in the format you posted it, it is difficult for us to be sure.

Comment: Just guessing about your second bat file, but what about `for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%A in ('type %*^|find "::"') do echo %%A`?